# Undefined variable _GET

Tags: php, variables, get, undefined

I got a problem with a php webapplication. It stops working after 10-20 hours for no reason because `$_GET` is not defined.

The request looks like:

```
http://host/index.php?id=1
```

the index file has a lil code snippet like:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
} else {
    die('wrong id');
}
```

A var_dump of `$_GET` returns `NULL`. A var_dump of `$_SERVER` shows the `REQUEST_METHOD` is GET and the `QUERY_STRING` is id=1. A `var_dump()` of `$_REQUEST` shows id => 1, so it's only `$_GET` that isn't working.

When that happens it happens for all webapplications on the server and for all users. After restarting the webserver everything is working again for some hours...

System is Windows 2008 R2, Apache 2.4.18 32 Bit/PHP 7.0.4 32 Bit.

Comment: Sounds like there is something wrong on the server?

Comment: Alankar More according to the php.net manual "This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0." So it shouldn't be relevant for a PHP 7.0.4 installation. Beside that it's pretty much the default php-production.ini with some minor modifications (paths, execution time, extensions gd2, mbstring, oci8, charset and date/time settings).

Comment: I know this is an obvious question, but is there anything in Apache/PHP error log? What happens if you try [$HTTP_GET_VARS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) (not superglobal and deprecated) instead of `$_GET`?

Comment: No errors besides thousands of requests with undefined variable _GET but nothing before that happens. Gonna try HTTP_GET_VARS if I see the error the next time. Most of the time another colleague will restart the Apache before I get the chance to look at the situation. At the end its a production system and a bunch of people need a working system in order to work so their is no time to test a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Using `is_numeric` function on GET value that is not set may give an error and stop your script.

Make sure that GET value is set before using is_numeric function on it.

```
if(!isset($_GET['id']))
{
    die('wrong id');
}
elseif(is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
}
else
{
    die('wrong id');
}
```

Comment: there is an isset before the is_numeric check. If _GET isn't set it will jump out of that if case and not checking for numeric.

Comment: If isset and is_numeric are in same if statement, then is_numeric will be still used even if GET value is not set

Comment: That's interessting because if I run an if statement with isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) without providing an id I don't get errors and the if statement is just skipped. When I remove the isset I get Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\ApachePHP\htdocs\index.php on line 2. If what you said is true I don't understand why I don't get the notice anyway.

Comment: **Sorry but @ValidSolutions is incorrect**; see [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). They are short-circuit operators. As soon as a condition is found that resolves the overall result, further evaluation stops. Example; `if (false && foo())` will never execute `foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

In case your $_REQUEST var holds the value but $_GET does not, there has been a  bug report filed: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73554